# changing the size of text_field_tag rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-helpers

I am using following options in my text_field_tag which is used as a search box. I want to change the width and height of the text_field tag.

```
 <%= text_field_tag(:search, value = nil, options = {:size => "200", :placeholder => "Search Events", :class => "round shadow"})%>
```

I am able to get all the desired effect except for the size. As far as I know the syntax is correct. I am also using bluprint.css. Just to be sure I commented out the blueprint css textarea default options.

```
/*textarea {width:390px;height:250px;padding:5px;}*/
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: there can be another rule for your text field

Comment: @user973254 what rule are you talking about?

Comment: about css rule, sorry I've forgot to say

Comment: @user973254 could you please elaborate on the css rule which you are talking about?

Comment: I am talking about css rule which overrides size of your text field, you've commented out textarea css rule, but is there any other rules which can affect text field tag?

Comment: @user973254 I think that the css rule is not affecting the styling I uncommented it and changed the parameters but it did not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an id or class to that `text_field_tag`, and then set the width and height in css. Note that `text_field_tag` generates a `<input type="text">`, not a `<textarea>`, so the css you mentioned is not modifying your tag.

Comment: Hi,I have assigned classes to the text_field_tag inside the options but when i try to manipulate the height of the text_box with that class in a css it does not work. If I try to assign a class outside the options then I get the error wrong number of arguments (4 for 3). Where should I put the id in the text_field_tag?

Comment: Now I see the [problem - your syntax is wrong. <%= text_field_tag(:search, nil, :placeholder => "Search Events", :class => "round shadow") %>